# Removing duplicates from Excel combo box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, populate

I currently have several combo box on a UserForm in excel that autopopulate from entries into specific columns in the workbook. However, these combo boxes automatically populate duplicates, and I do not want that. How should I adjust my code to only populate with unique values? Thanks.

Here is my code for the combo boxes:

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        txtContractVehicle.List = .Range("E2:E" & .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        txtCapability.List = .Range("F2:F" & .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        txtAgency.List = .Range("G2:G" & .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        txtDepartment.List = .Range("H2:H" & .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        txtSocioeconomic.List = .Range("I2:I" & .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Provide a range that doesn't include duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

you could a helper function to "filter" some passed array and leave unique values onlyfor instance exploiting `Dictionary` object

```
Function RemoveDuplicates(vals As Variant) As Variant
    Dim val As Variant
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each val In vals
            .Item(val) = 1
        Next
        RemoveDuplicates = .Keys
    End With
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        txtContractVehicle.list = RemoveDuplicates(.Range("E2:E" & .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Value)
        ...
    End With
End Sub
```